# Why Xcode code completion for core location classes is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-location, code-completion

I'm new to iOS and I'm trying to build a simple location base app. I have an issue with Xcode 6.1 (6A1046a) which is not showing `CoreLocation` classes and methods in the code completion.

I've tried to link the `CoreLocation` framework to the project but it still not working. It's really a pain because I have to check the doc for every constructor or methods.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I've tried to delete the `Derived Data` in the organizer (Window > Organiser > Derived Data -> delete)
But it's not changing anything and of course I've tried to restart Xcode 10 times.
Anyone can help with this issue? Thanks

Comment: Related?: [Xcode 6 Swift code completion not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25883905/456814).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to fix this **manually deleting** all the file in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

```
$ rm -Rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

And now I get the code completion correctly:

[image]

Comment: Go in user=>Library=>Developer=>Xcode=>DeriveData and delete the Data of folder"Derive data" and restart Xcode.

Comment: This was not working for me, I had to delete the folder manually