# Xcode keeps remaking derived data folder after I delete it

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Autocomplete won't work in Xcode 6 anymore. I searched around and I read that deleting the derived data folder will fix this issue. Every time I delete it, it comes back, and it then won't autocomplete anymore.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Quit Xcode. Trash all the content of Derived Data folder. Relaunch Xcode (the files and folders are recreated if Xcode is still running when you empty the folder).

Comment: Take a look here also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883905/xcode-6-swift-code-completion-not-working

Comment: @EricD. I tried that, but for some reason autocomplete still won't work. Now, autocomplete works on some things, but it's not working on a variable I just created. When I declare the variable, it's fine with that. When I try to work with the variable after it's declaration, "Expected declaration" comes up.

Comment: @Tushar Yeah that was one that I looked at for help, but my derived folder isn't inside my Library folder, but it's inside my project folder. I tried deleting it from my project folder but that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I figured out the issue! I wasn't declaring the variable I needed to use inside a method inside the class.