# swift code completion doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I don't know what's wrong with my xcode. My project could run on my iphone properly (so I guess there is nothing wrong with my project). But in the Xcode editor, I couldn't "jump" to function or variables definition. it shows

[image]

this could be fixed by just restarting Xcode.However, after about a few minutes, it doesn't work again...

I already check [Xcode 6 Swift code completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883905/xcode-6-swift-code-completion-not-working)
But no luck..

my swift version is 1.2, and Xcode version is Version 6.4 (6E35b)

any one help?

Comment: Nope, it's a bug in Xcode, if you feel like it go to bugreporter.apple.com and file a bug, however there might already be some duplicates :)

Comment: @HAS ok，keep waiting for the next xcode update...thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the Swift support in XCode is still very buggy. It gets better with every release, but it's far away from perfect.

For me, the only thing that seems to help is to delete DerivedData and restart Xcode.