# Xcode beginner functions won't show up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

im new to Xcode and this may be s stupid question and im sorry but i dont know how to fix it, every time begin typing

```
.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation
```

, nothing automatically pops up allowing me to select it. Does anyone know what this problems is or how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 Swift code completion not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883905/xcode-6-swift-code-completion-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

For performance, [CoreGraphics](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics) types (like [`CGAffineTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform)) were made to be C structs rather than Objective C classes. C structs can't contain methods, constructors, etc. To simulate this, raw functions were made like [`CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1455666-cgaffinetransformmakerotation?language=objc) to perform operations on these structs.

Swift supports struct methods, so in Swift, these raw functions are imported as methods on the [`CGAffineTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform) struct. You're looking for [`CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455666-init)