# Use TypeAlias in other class

Tags: swift, type-alias

I want to use alias defined in the **Class1** class . I want to use it into **Class2**

```
import UIKit

class Class1: NSObject {
    typealias tp = () -> Void 


}


import UIKit

class Class2: NSObject {    
    func pingTest(){
        var test:tp?
    }
}
```

**Class2** throws compile time error at **var test:tp?**

Also, the autocompletion does not work. Screen the shot attached with this email. I tried the following thing but that didn't work for me ([XCode 6 isn't autocompleting in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133039/xcode-6-isnt-autocompleting-in-swift)).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the TypeAlias as `public` and that too outside the class.

The other option is to define protocol and inherit to any class.